# Poweroff problem

Tags: shutdown, systemd

When  I try to poweroff, the pc doesn't poweroff, the harddisk continues (although slowly) to remain active, and on my keyboard is blinking rarely capslock.

I tried kernel 5.15 didn't solve my problem.
I find now the following message before screen turns off:
**systemd-shutdown cannot detach DM**

Update: I have installed systemd 248.3. Perhaps poweroff was Ok
with anterior version of systemd. I found something related I think
[systemd bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1958590)

My system configuration is:
OS: Kubuntu 21.10 x86_64
Kernel: 5.13.0-25-generic
DE: Plasma 5.23.5
CPU: AMD A6-9225 RADEON R4
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon
Also has cryptsetup and LVM I think.

What is important though is how could I find messages around shutdown. I mean, there is a moment when messages are no longer written down in logs. Appear fast in screen just before it hangs.
How could I write those messages?

thanks in advance

Comment: Problem solved today, after upgrading to kernel 5.13.0-28 ! Now my laptop can poweroff and reboot.